# Averaging models in cross validation in neural network implementation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-validation

I am implanting my first NN and I want to use cross validation. I have diposoted 20% of my data aside for testing and the rest is my training set.

I have divided my training set to 10 sections and I am iterating over them 10 times, each time picking another section to test a model trained on the other 9 sections.

I have 10 models with 10 entropy errors. how do I make it into 1 model? I have seen a lot of tutorials stating I should average them for classifiers other than NN. how do I average for NN?

- Do I simply take all 10 `W1` matrices (for the first layer) and average the weights values? then proceed to do the same for `b1`, `W2`, `b2` and so on?
- If so, how do I then calculate the entropy for the total model?
- If not, how do I pick the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "merge" neural networks as layers are generally nonlinear. To estimate the overall error you can just average your ten errors. If you want to apply this model in the real world just train a new network on the full data.

Also note that you did not use a validation set in your split. If you are optimizing hyperparameters on the test set you are bound to falsify your results as you let the test set influence your classifier, thus introducing bias.

Check this for a more detailed explanation on how to use cross validation with neural networks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889637/how-to-use-k-fold-cross-validation-in-a-neural-network

Comment: As I have stated in the question, 20% of the data is deposited before hand for testing. The cross validation is preformed on the remaining 80%. Have I got it wrong?

Comment: Depends on whether you optimize hyperparamters. Cf.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25891428/1902741